Problems with breaking the high E string on Guitar
I own a SSH Fender Squire Strat, i have been having issues with tuning only the high E string. When i bought it, the fender strings out of the box worked fine till 2 months after which the high E broke. i replaced it with a cheaper single string, it broke within 2 days, i tried replacing it several times and it still never lasted longer than 3 days. The problem was only with the high E. After getting frustrated i kept it for some months as i also got busy in IRL stuff. I picked it up again recently and changed the whole set with d'addario XL, after 2 rounds playing (includes tuning and un-tuning the guitar), the image i am attaching is the result. Also, all the strings that broke, broke from the same region which is near the string posts. Also, while bending high E i sometimes get creaking sounds and while tuning/untuning the high E and B string i hear creaking sound almost every revolution. Really frustrated and not able to understand what the issue is. I guessed of some pointy edge inside the string post and tried to file with metal as well as gave the guitar to my shopkeeper who tried to do stuff as well, but it seems like i am again going down the same route. Pl. guide 

I wish I had an answer for you.
I believe you are on the right track with the "sharp edge inside the post aperature" theory.
One suggestion;
Remove the E string and the B string next to it, and swap out the tuner mechanisms, one for the other. Then restring the guitar and play it as you normally might.
If the B string breaks off, then you have identified your problem.

You mention untuning the guitar. It's not something we normally do. Maybe that's a contributory factor.

"the image i am attaching is the result" - What are you trying to show us with this image? It's hard to see what's going on because of the angle. It does look like the strings might not have been locked to the tuning machines effectively when they were put on. Again, it's hard to be sure because we can't see what's really going on with the strings and tuning machines from this angle.

Sounds like you are on the right track. It’s always a good idea to check the string itself whenever it breaks: if it always breaks in the same place on the string this is often a guitar problem rather than a string problem. As others have noted, this is often because there is a slightly sharp edge somewhere.


changed the whole set with d'addario XL

If the high E string has not broken since you put on the D'Addario set, then I would guess that the actual problem was using low-quality strings. If the current high E string last much longer than the others, then you'll have learned one reason why it helps to spend a bit more on strings.

while bending high E i sometimes get creaking sounds and while tuning/untuning the high E and B string i hear creaking sound almost every revolution

This is very common and is caused by the string sticking at the nut. The nut is the plastic bar with six slots filed in it for each string that is at the top of the fretboard, near the tuning machines. If the creaking started right after you put on the new set of D'Addarios, then you might have chosen a set of strings that are slightly thicker than the factory set, which means the nut slots might be slightly too small.
Either way, sticking at the nut is a common problem, even when the nut slots are the right size. One way to reduce sticking at the nut is to loosen the strings enough so you can move them out of the slot and then run the tip of a sharpened graphite pencil in each slot. This should rub off some graphite powder into the slot which will act as a lubricant. The best solution is to have the nut slots expanded slightly, but then they can be loose if you change back to a thinner gauge of strings.
One final note is I suggest changing all of the strings periodically. Every 50-60 playing hours is not too often. When you change them, do some research online about how to string and guitar and follow the process carefully. It will take longer than you'd probably like the first several times, but learning to string effectively will make everything better as you continue playing guitar.
